# How to configure KafkaAppender in LOG4J2.XML

Tags: java, xml, apache-kafka, log4j2, appender

I am trying to configure the `Kafka 9` supplied `KafkaLog4jAppender` with `log4j2.xml`.

My log4j2.xml file resembles this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="org.apache.kafka.log4jappender"
    status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Kafka name="Kafka"  topic="log-test">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date %message" />
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">localhost:9092</Property>
        </Kafka>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Kafka" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO" />
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My log output is

```
2016-03-08 12:14:27,480 ERROR Error processing element Kafka: CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2016-03-08 12:14:27,520 ERROR Unable to locate appender Kafka for logger
```

How do I specify the full class name of the `KafkaLog4jAppender`?

Is my only option to use log4j 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue by `Apache Log4j 2.5`